# Feed sonarqube jacoco widget with csv/html reports (instead of *.exec)

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco

I got a root maven project, under which there are many independent modules (e.g. module_A, module_B, etc.).

One of these module is my integration-tests module, and it uses all the above external modules.
In order to have code coverage for all modules used by integration-tests, I use a workaround based on maven-ant (see [this blog post](http://intellectualcramps.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/jacoco-tycho-and-coverage-reports/)).

### Problem is:

The above generates csv/html report, yet sonarqube jacoco widget parses only jacoco*.exec files - which results in 0% code coverage.

### Question is:

---

### EDIT

here's an [example project](https://github.com/tompere/unit-and-integration-jacoco-coverage-with-sonar) for the problem above.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use that workaround. You can provide Sonar with integration tests coverage file with following property (you shall use it while executing sonar:sonar goal):

```
-Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=<coverage_file>
```

Here is detailed documentation:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Integration+Tests+for+Java+Project

To sum up:

1. Compile all your modules.
2. Execute integration tests with jacoco enabled.
3. Execute Maven Sonar build adding mentioned property in command line.

I have prepared example project generating both unit and integration coverage results, you can check it here:

https://github.com/octosan/unit-and-integration-jacoco-coverage-with-sonar

You have to:

- download newest Sonarqube version and start it
- execute command:

> ```
> mvn clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=<absolute_path>/itest/target/jacoco-it.exec
> ```

- add integration coverage widged in project dashboard in Sonar

Comment: the above doesn't support multi-module maven project (see [jacoco open issue](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/69)), thus it can't be used.

Comment: Hmm, at first glance it seems to me that multi-module has nothing to do with jacoco here. jacoco is only used to generate coverage files, which are then interpreted by Maven sonar plugin (which also handles multi-modules). I will check it in detail later if I will find some time.

Comment: you're right multi-module is a maven sonar plugin issue, not sonar alone, and that what I was referring to, see a [thread I've posted in jacoco google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jacoco/9NNAlwuvOwk) . Thanks anyway

Comment: I have prepared example configuration which works with Sonar. You can check it here: https://github.com/octosan/unit-and-integration-jacoco-coverage-with-sonar . Just clone, download newest Sonarqube version and start it, and execute command: mvn clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=<absolute_path>/itest/target/jacoco-it.exec You will have then two coverages report: unit and integration. Don't forget to add integration coverage widged in project dashboard.

Comment: thanks for the effort! I've forked your example to demonstrate the more complex scenario I've run into. It can be great if you will have a look. see my edit in the question. thanks again!

Comment: No problem! I have cloned your project and without any modification called mentioned above command. Integration tests coverage has been generated for created by you class. Are you sure you have provided absolute path to integration coverage, for example: -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=/home/user/dev/projects/jacoco-usecase/itest/target/jacoco-it.exec  Additionally, don't look at aggregated coverage, just look at integration tests coverage.

Comment: did you see code coverage for methods of 'api-one' and 'api-two' modules?

Comment: Yes, all are covered except: public String methodNotTestedAtAll(String string, int intt) {